# How to convert hyperspectral image to RGB in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I have a problem with extracting 3 bands under the names R, G, and B, and then using those bands as 3 colour channels for RGB pictures. It is a hyperspectral image and it has 103 bands opposite to the normal RGB image which contains just 3. The one who gave me this question to solve, described it as something very basic, however, I am having a very difficult time with it. I may have syntax problems with **Matlab**. The picture comes as a .mat file. with the size of **610x340x103**.
I used different codes, searched forums etc. But I failed. here is the code I tried last time.

```
load("PaviaU.mat")
Blue=paviaU(:,:,7);
imwrite(Blue,"Blue.jpg")
newBlue=imread("Blue.jpg");
imshow(newBlue)
imagesc(newBlue) %*this line gives the result as a scaled image*

Green=paviaU(:,:,21);
imwrite(Green,"Green.jpg")
newGreen=imread("Green.jpg");
imshow(newGreen)

Red=paviaU(:,:,53);
imwrite(Red,"Red.jpg")
newRed=imread("Red.jpg");
imshow(newRed)

rgbImage = paviaU(:,:,[newRed,newGreen,newBlue])
```

when I use `imagesc(Red)` instead of `imshow` I see pictures as a result, but it is not what I would like to see. Also, I analysed this .mat file on the App section of Matlab where there is a hyperspectral image app, I could not observe the spectrum because band information was absent. However, I think, inside the library of image processing there is a file with the name of **paviaU.dat** that file works, and inside the App, I observed the spectrum and played with it.
What is the point I don't understand here? Is there a solution? You can find that **PaviaU.mat** file with the variable inside as **paviaU** through this link [PaviaU.mat](https://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/uploads/e/ee/PaviaU.mat)

Comment: try `imshow(rgbImage,[])` ? The issue is that RGB images need to be either 0-1 or 0-255. You need to either change the visualization range, or the data.  You have tons of text explaining many thought processes that are likely not relevant. Can you try tto clarify what are you trying to do, what is the expected result, and why the current result is not as expected?

Comment: ''I have a problem with extracting 3 bands under the names R, G, and B, and then using those bands as 3 colour channels for RGB pictures. It is a hyperspectral image and it has 103 bands opposite to the normal RGB image which contains just 3.''
what is not clear here? Someone who did image processing in Matlab especially hyperspectral would clearly understand what I would like to achieve here. My thought process was very close to the answer below.

Comment: That was clear, I answered it in my first 2 words. The rest was not, or superfluous. I was trying to get you to improve your question for better user response, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, in MATLAB the range of RGB images should be [0, 1] (for type `double`).

Dividing by the maximum value is a simple way for converting the range to [0, 1] (assuming input pixels are positive).

```
rgbImage = rgbImage / max(rgbImage(:));
```

---

When showing a single channel image as Grayscale, we may use `imshow(I, [])`.
For inspecting pixel values, we may add `impixelinfo` after `imshow` (we may also add a title):

```
figure;
imshow(Blue, []);
title('Blue');
impixelinfo
```

---

The RGB image looks dark, probably because the images are captured without Gamma correction.
For applying Gamma correction, according to [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) standard, we may use [lin2rgb](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/lin2rgb.html) function:

```
srgbImage = lin2rgb(rgbImage);
```

---

Code sample:

```
load("PaviaU.mat")

Blue = paviaU(:,:,7);
figure;imshow(Blue, []);title('Blue');impixelinfo

Green = paviaU(:,:,21);
figure;imshow(Green, []);title('Green');impixelinfo

Red = paviaU(:,:,53);
figure;imshow(Red, []);title('Red');impixelinfo

rgbImage = cat(3, Red, Green, Blue); % Concatenate Red, Green and Blue channels.
rgbImage = rgbImage / max(rgbImage(:)); % Convert to range [0, 1]

figure;imshow(rgbImage);title('rgbImage');impixelinfo

srgbImage = lin2rgb(rgbImage); % Apply Gamma correction.
figure;imshow(srgbImage);title('srgbImage');impixelinfo

srgbImage = im2uint8(srgbImage); % Convert from double in range [0, 1] to uint8 in range [0, 255] (optional).
imwrite(srgbImage, 'srgbImage.png'); % Save image for testing.
```

---

Output `srgbImage` image:
[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much. I understood now. I'm a beginner in image processing. Do you have any material, reference, or method that you can share? I'd like to learn faster and more effectively.

Comment: Image processing is a very wide subject. I can't point you to something specific. Look for "image processing tutorial" in Google. You may start with [MATLAB image processing tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/getting-started-with-image-processing-toolbox.html).